# Access files created by another program

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, thread-safety

I have a thread that parses the files from a folder A and move them to another folder B. The A folder files are created by another program that I do not have access to.
so sometimes I can not access the folder A files because they are used by another process (probably the process of the other program).

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

There would be no issue accessing files created by any process unless application user has rights to access it.

The issue that you are facing is because of the reason that the files created by another program may not be properly released or closed after creating or modifying them, so please make sure that your other program releases the resources safely.

```
var file = File.Create(path);
file.Close();
```

Also while accessing same resources in multiple threads you need to take care of thread safety, as you are having two different processes all you can do is to wait within a process until the file is released by another process.

Comment: This is the problem, i dont have acces to other program.

Comment: In that case, how are you ensuring you are accessing correct version of the updated file? I mean does the other program updates file on a scheduled basis or something else and how to do you know when to access it using your program?

Comment: Anyways you will be having a thread to parse files, what you need to make sure is both the programs access the files in a thread-safe manner.